# linkButton Click Event in Grid View is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am using linkbutton to insert data in the asp.net grid view through textbox. But in spite of correct code my button is not performing action. 
Here is my ASPX code

```
            <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="Insertkey" OnClick="Insertkey_Click" runat="server">INSERT</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
```

Here is my C# code

```
    protected void Insertkey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Title"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Tbox")).Text;

        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Pic"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Pbox")).Text;



        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Content"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Cbox")).Text;
    }
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the Insertkey_Click, is it hitting that code? One thing that stands out is the code "GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("Pbox")).Text" is finding the control from the footer. This control doesn't exist in your footer template code

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command event instead of click, then handle the grid's RowCommand event and see what the command name is.

Controls that postback, such as the link button, behave differently when in templated controls such as the gridview, primarily since they can't really be declared in the same way since they're in a template.